# PostgreSQL: find information about user defined types

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types, system-tables

Where is information about user-defined types stored?

Are there some tables which contain information about the fields of a user-defined composite type, their names, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The catalog pg_type stores information about data types. Base types and enum types (scalar types) are created with CREATE TYPE, and domains with CREATE DOMAIN.

More information about pg_type plz visit
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-type.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
pg_type does not store information about fields that costitute composite types. Do you know, if it exists, which table store this kind of information?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question very well, if you want to know the information about all the columns 
of a table , you can query  the catalog pg_attribute。(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html)

Comment: By the way,  pg_type.typtype is b for a base type, c for a composite type (e.g., a table's row type), 
d for a domain,   e for an enum type, or p for a pseudo-type. See also typrelid and typbasetype

Comment: Here's an example of what I think is being asked here (and how I ended up here, too). We've got a composite type named "listing_room" containing data (for example) "name text, floor int, width decimal, depth decimal" (yes, I know this isn't valid SQL, but I'm just making a point). I can now trundle off and create a table "listings" with columns "id serial, address text, master_bedroom room". So, using any database interface (in my case, JDBC), I can determine that "master_bedroom" is of type "room", but how can I query the server to dynamically determine "room"'s actual structure?

Answer (score 5):

Information about the fields constituting a composite type can be retrieved like this:

```
select * from pg_attribute where attrelid =
  (select typrelid from pg_type where typname = 't_employee')
```

where `t_employee` would be the name of the composite type.

Comment: Although @francs's answer links off to the appropriate documentation, this answer is immediately usable, even 5 years later!